# how to get newly added child in firebase web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get newly added node value in firebase?
I want to get the newly added child node in my collection .

I've tried this, but it gives me the last child values:

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('testingchat/');

starCountRef.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    console.log("abc");
    console.log(snapshot.ref.parent.key);
    console.log("abc");}
```

As you can see in picture I want values from 3 including the '3' so I can use this to identify users from my sql database.

[image: as you can see in picture i want values from 3 including the '3' so i can use this to identify users from my sql database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid nesting the database as explained [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html), change your database to the following, :

```
testingchat
       3
        email          : "abc@gmail.com"
        profile_picture: "abc"
        username       : "ok"
```

then do the following:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref("testingchat");

ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
 snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
   var key       = childSnapshot.key;
   var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    });
});
```

Here `key` property will retrieve `3` and `childSnapshot.val()` will retrieve the data under `3`.